# VITE + REACT + TS env variables doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, vite

I have React + TS + Vite APP.
In the root folder created - `.env.production`.
Added in this file env variable - `VITE_TEST=blablabla`

Trying to check availability by `console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_TEST)`, but gets `undefined`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the mode flag

```
"dev:p": "vite --mode production", // this needs to be set while running locally
"build:p": "vite build", // the default build mode should be production
```

[Source](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode)

Comment: That helped. Thank you!